# Punctate words if it contains more then X number of words

Tags: php

When a word gets to long it messes the text up.... how can I fix this?

Example:

Make a word with 4 chars like "cats" into "ca..."

How would I do this?

Comment: Do you mean more than x number of letters? Please give sample input and output.

Comment: in what way does the text get messed up?  Can you provide examples?

Comment: Do you mean truncate a stream of characters when a length of characters unbroken by spaces exceeds some size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean words get too long, and they widen the column it's in?  You could use a regular expression to fix it: Perhaps find any consecutive string of e.g. 200 non-whitespace characters and insert a space so that it can break to a new line there:

```
$text = preg_replace('/(\S{200})/gs', '\1 ', $text);
```

**EDIT:**  To loka's question:  Similarly,

```
$text = preg_replace('/(\S{200})\S*/gs', '\1...', $text);
```

Comment: `\S` is a "non-whitespace" character in regexland, and might be useful.